# shape file contour label values

Tags: label, contour, gdal, shapefile

I tried making shape files of pressure from netcdf files using the following commands using gdal:

gdal_contour -a pressure -i 4 -off 0 pressure.nc pressure.shp

I noticed that when displaying the graph in mapserver I get label values such as 1010.00000000 whereas I want the labels to be whole numbers. How do I tweak this code to get whole numbers for pressure contour labels in map server?

I have noticed that in the netcdf file pressure.nc that the pressure values have three trailing decimal points after them so a pressure value in the netcdf file will be 1010.000 instead of 1010.  I also noticed that viewing the dbf file.  Do I need to fix the netcdf file to display intergers?  If so how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tweak you'd do in the MapServer layer itself by defining a CLASS element with a tostring expression (Mapserver >= 6.0) as the LABEL TEXT field, e.g.

```
LAYER
  NAME "pressure_contours"
  DATA pressure
  ...
  CLASS
    ...
    LABEL
      TEXT tostring([ELEV],"%.0f") + "m"
    END
    ...
  END
END
```

This should provide you with a label that looks like "1010m". You can always drop the '+ "m"' if you're not worried about units.